# xlmhg 2.5.4 has requirement plotly>=3, but you'll have plotly 2.7.0 which is incompatible

Tags: plotly

I tried to install `celseq2` in my `Ubuntu` system.

```
ERROR: xlmhg 2.5.4 has requirement plotly>=3, but you'll have plotly 2.7.0 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li@lion-Desktop-590-p0xxx:~$ pip install plotly
```